# Deletion of Nodes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete a row on clicking of a button. It works fine unless I am within  a table. My JSP has a combination of 50 rows in a table and after that we nest the the tables. Now, my problem is if I want to delete the last row from the previous table, how should I do that?

I am attaching the screenshot of the UI and Debugger HTML View too. Any suggestions will be helpful.

[DROW] here are the different rows under which we have a tree structure. We need to climb up to each row first and then move down to the lastChild to delete the last row.

> This is only possible here if my previousRow contains the last rows val. I am unable to get down to it.

```
function removeAnotherResponse(arg0, data, response, request){

// Make sure the response has everything we need
if(arguments==null || arguments.length<4  || !request.content || request.content==null || !request.content.groupUniqueId || request.content.groupUniqueId==null){
    return;
}

// Check for true response
if(!data || data==null || !data[0] || !data[0].removedSuccess || data[0].removedSuccess!=true){
    return;
}

var groupUniqueId=request.content.groupUniqueId;

// Get the add another button row and add the new row before it.
var addAnotherRow=document.getElementById("ADD_"+groupUniqueId);
if(addAnotherRow==null) return;

    var previousRow=document.getElementById("ADD_"+groupUniqueId).previousSibling;  
    addAnotherRow.parentNode.removeChild(previousRow);



showOrHideAddRemoveButtons(groupUniqueId, data[0].removeButton, data[0].addButton);
updateSectionCount(groupUniqueId, false);
getPortCount(groupUniqueId);
```

}

Comment: add code not the screenshot.

Comment: @Mritunjay.. I have added the code I was using to delete rows within a table. I am unable to move to the above row which has nested table in it, as displayed in the debug screenshot.

Comment: `id` attribute value should be unique per element. here you should use class not `id` of the same values.

Comment: i am creating these rows and columns dynamically from the script itself.

Comment: 1. When Mritunjay says "add code not screenshot" he's talking about your html.

2. You need to fix your html, it's really invalid and will likely break something in weird ways.  You should not have nested "tr" elements and IDs need to be unique within the document.

Fix those problems first and you might find your other problem easier to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for suggesting me to correct the html code.

UI element was indeed creating a problem for me in other ways. Now, instead of creating a new, I have found out other way to handle this and my HTML code has got simpler. PFB the script changes which have been made. Thanks for all the suggestions :)

```
if (document.getElementById("ID" + gID) != null) {

    innerElement = document.getElementById("ID_TD_" + gID);
    innerElement.innerHTML = innerElement.innerHTML + responseHTML;

} else {

    innerElement = document.createElement("td");
    innerElement.setAttribute("id", "ID_TD_" + gID);

    newElement.appendChild(innerElement);
    innerElement.innerHTML = responseHTML;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML fragment which you post seems have some problems (id duplicates, usage `<tr>` as parent of other `<tr>`). I try still answer on your main question how to remove row of the table. You can use [deleteRow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp) method of DOM [table](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp) object. The [rows](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp) collection can be used to access to existing rows and `deleteRow` and [insertRow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp) allows you to modify the table.

Comment: Here I want to move to that row as in my current approach I am doing. When I am traversing in a table I can easily do that with the code above. But when all 50 rows in a table are deleted and I want to move to the above row which again has a table as displayed, I am unable to do so.

Comment: @Bhaskar: Sorry, but I can't full follow you. The code fragment which you posted uses only DOM methods like `parentNode` and `removeChild` which are **common** for every HTML element. DOM API have some **specific** methods like `deleteRow` which allows you to simplify the work in case of working with **specific** DOM elements like `<table>`. You main question is: *How to delete the last row from some specific table?*. I suggest you to select the table by id and then use `deleteRow` to delete the row which you want to delete.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the change. Probably i will try fixing my jsp first and will post my answer if my issue is resolved.

Comment: @Bhaskar: You are welcome! The JSP/HTML need be really fixed. Try to use `class` attribute instead of `id` if more as one element are exist. The parent of `<tr>` should be `<tbody>` and it's parent `<table>` which you can places in `<td>` of another `<table>`. Instead of `removeChild` I recommend you to use `deleteRow` method of DOM `table` object. `rows.length` get you information about number of rows. So you `deleteRow` with 0-based index of row to delete the row.